# Cannot download & install app APK from own webpage

Tags: android, asp.net, download, apk

I'm trying to have my apps available for download on a website, however, when I upload the APK file, it cannot be found by the browser.

When zipping the APK, it is detected. However, not all phones can install from a ZIP - I have had mixed results.

Why can't I simply upload an APK and have a URL point to it for a download? Why am I getting a 404 and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Where are you hosting your apk? What web server are you using? You may need to set the Content-Type header

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why can't I simply upload an APK and have a URL point to it for a download?

You can. Plenty of people do it. There are entire Web sites dedicated to doing it, albeit usually with pirated content.

> Why am I getting a 404

Because the URL you are entering into the browser is not the URL where the file is at on the server. This is the cause of approximately 100% of 404 errors, across the Internet, regardless of circumstance.

> what can I do to avoid it?

Use the proper URL. Also, be sure to set the server's MIME type configuration map to serve up your file as `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.

Comment: Using the exact same path, I don't get a 404 when the APK is zipped. How is that not the URL where the file is on the server? Just saw the last bit of your post, I haven't tried the MIME type config. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Usually, a Web server will use some default MIME type for unrecognized files (e.g., `application/octet-stream`), but perhaps your host has an odd configuration. By way of example, if you download [http://misc.commonsware.com/Now-debug.apk](http://misc.commonsware.com/Now-debug.apk), it will install on your Android device. This is an APK file uploaded to Amazon S3, which automatically handles this particular MIME type.

Comment: @CommonsWare I too  am using  amazon aws3  server to  host my apk   but i  get  "cant open  file" error ,for AWS3  too  does this MIME  type has to be  set manually ? how can  i check/edit  Mime  type of a particular  file  uploaded in aws3 ?

Comment: @amIT: ",for AWS3 too does this MIME type has to be set manually ?" -- probably, as the APK MIME type is a bit obscure. "how can i check/edit Mime type of a particular file uploaded in aws3 ?" -- I have no idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks ,can  you please share the tool /procedure  used by you to upload onAWS3  i use a  plugin in firefox  called "S3  organizer".

Comment: @CommonsWare even I'm facing the same problem, when i change the extension to .APK the file starts downloading but normal .apk results in 404 please help [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31760145/4481968)

Answer (score 11):

This is what i did in my asp.net application

My Application hosted under Window server 2008r2 having IIS 7

Step 1: In .aspx page add hyperlink set navigateurl as file path

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkdwnload" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Application_Android/MyAndroidAppAame.apk">Download MyApp</asp:HyperLink>
```

Step 2: Web.config add mimeMap element under staticContent

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive"/>
    </staticContent>
```

</system.webServer>

Comment: Thanks this what the reason, and i was actually using an IIS server

Answer (score 5):

```
in case you are using .net core,
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
...
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            // Add new mappings`enter code here`
            provider.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/octet-stream";
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Upload a web.config file in the directory where you keep the apk file

The content of the web.config should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now you can download the apk file..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it is working

This is what i did in my asp.net application

My Application hosted under Window server 2008r2 having IIS 7

Step 1: In .aspx page add hyperlink set navigateurl as file path

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkdwnload" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Application_Android/MyAndroidAppAame.apk">Download MyApp</asp:HyperLink>
```

Step 2: Web.config add mimeMap element under staticContent on same path

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive"/>
    </staticContent>
```

Comment: Downvoted - reason the answer posted by you is word to word same of mine which i posted 2 years ago. Don't be a copypaster

Answer (score 0):

In Window Server go to IIS Manager, select your virtual directory and select MIME type

Add new MIME type -> Extension "apk" Type -> "application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk"

be sure add .apk extention

It will enable the apk file to download from Windows Server.