# can't download .apk file from server

Tags: server

I have an apk file on my server (which is hosted on Hostinger) CentOS OS

now I want users to download that file from my server.

but when I point the url to the apk location it says 404 page not found while I know there are entire web sites dedicated to doing it.

I tried modifying htaccess file

```
AddType application/octet-stream .apk
```

then

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk
```

then

```
<Files *.*>
ForceType application/octet-stream
</Files>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

even tried doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784154/4481968

PS. all other file formats get downloaded, even .APK file gets downloaded but not .apk (why is that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem with Hostinger and wrote to the support.

They said, .apk files are blocked for security reasons.

However, rename the file to .APK, that is working as well and you can reach it on your server.

Comment: okay, that explains! but my friend had hosted his site on Hostinger as well and from his site downloading was possible...anyway I'm changing my hosting provider. going for a cloud VPS now!

Answer (score 0):

Create file with name .htaccess and just paste the below code in it and move this file on your server where your apk file is placed

AddType application/octet-stream .apk

AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk

ForceType application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

I know it is already answered. But anyone still facing the issue even after making changes suggested above, change `minifyEnabled true` to `minifyEnabled false` if it is enabled in `build.gradle` file of your app.

Comment: How does this help? Please elaborate.